# axios-mock-adapter not fetch my fake data in react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, axios

So I'm trying to test a react typescript component where I fetch with axios so I try to mock that api call.

Here my test
Comments.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Comments } from '../components/Comments';
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

describe('RiskPatternCard', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {

    });

    test('renders the Comments component', () => {
        render(<Comments className="test-class" />);
        expect(screen.getByTestId('comments_header')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    test('displays the correct number of comments', () => {


        const mockedData = [
            { id: 1, data: { title: 'Comment 1', body: 'Body 1' }, userObject: { fullname: 'User 1' } },
            { id: 2, data: { title: 'Comment 2', body: 'Body 2' }, userObject: { fullname: 'User 2' } },
            { id: 3, data: { title: 'Comment 3', body: 'Body 3' }, userObject: { fullname: 'User 3' } },
        ];

        const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        // const comments = [{ id: 1, comment: 'Test comment' }];
        mock.onGet('http://localhost:8000/comments?case_id=123').reply(200, mockedData);

        const { getByTestId } = render(<Comments className="test-class" />);
        waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId('comments-header')).toBeInTheDocument());

        const comment = getByTestId('comments_header');
        expect(comment).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(comment).toHaveTextContent('Comments');

        expect(screen.getByTestId('comment_fullname')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
})
```

Here is my comments.tsx component:

```
export const Comments: React.FC<{ className: string }> = ({className}) => {

    const {caseId, hasAccess} = useRiskPatternDetailsPageContext();
    const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [comments, setComments] = useCommentsDataFetch(caseId);
    const {currentUser} = useAuth();

    return (
        <>
            <div className={`card ${className}`}>
                {/* begin::Header */}
                [code...]
                </div>
                {/* end::Header */}
                {/* begin::Body */}
                <div className='card-body py-3'>
                    <div className='tab-content'>
                        {/* begin::Tap pane */}
                        <div className='tab-pane fade show active' id='kt_table_widget_7_tab_1'>
                            {/* begin::Table container */}
                            <div className='table-responsive' style={{height: 180}}>
                                {/* begin::Table */}
                                <table className='table overflow-auto align-middle gs-0 gy-3'>
                                    {/* begin::Table head */}
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th className='p-0 w-50px'></th>
                                        <th className='p-0 min-w-150px'></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    {/* end::Table head */}
                                    {/* begin::Table body */}
                                    <tbody>
                                    {comments && comments.map((comment, index) => (
                                        <tr key={comment.id ? comment.id : index}>
                                            <td>
                                                <div className='symbol symbol-50px'>
                                                    {
                                                        comment.userObject?.pic ?
                                                            <img src={toAbsoluteUrl(comment.userObject?.pic)}
                                                                 alt={comment.userObject && comment.userObject.fullname}/>
                                                            :
                                                            <img src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/svg/avatars/blank.svg')}
                                                                 alt={comment.userObject && comment.userObject.fullname}/>
                                                    }
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href='src/app/generel-modules/RiskPatternsTableModule/components#'
                                                   className='text-dark fw-bolder text-hover-primary mb-1 fs-6' data-cy='comment_fullname' data-testid='comment_fullname'>
                                                    {comment.userObject?.fullname} - {comment.data.title}
                                                </a>
                                                <span
                                                    className='text-muted fw-bold d-block fs-8'>Created - {comment.convertedTimestamp}</span>
                                                <span className='text-dark fw-bold d-block fs-7' data-cy='comment_body'>
                                                    {comment.data.body}
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}
                                    </tbody>
                                    {/* end::Table body */}
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            {/* end::Table */}
                        </div>
                        {/* end::Tap pane */}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* end::Body */}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Its like when I run the test it not runs though when I map over my comments array stored in the usestate comments.

Where I have fetch in from my backend API with a useEffect